# Mash Boiler – What's a good boiler?

Tags: mash, mash-tun, boil-kettle, boil-equipment

i'm new to the brewing game and am currently waiting for a few whole grain brews to come of age.

One thing i'd like to do is purchase a larger mash boiler and dedicate a bit of space in the shed for my 'micro-brewery'.

What makes a good boiler? Where should I start?

Any suggestions would be gratefully received!

Rik

Answer (score 3):

Many people use propane turkey fryer setups, consisting of a large propane burner and kettle.  The kettle is usually around 6.5-7 gal. so it's barely big enough for a 5 gal. batch, but it works.  I won awards for beer made with one.  The kettles are often AL, but don't let that throw you.  It's perfectly fine and safe.

Comment: That's great advise thanks! We've had a look at them on eBay and they seem a reasonable investment. Do you use a cooling coil also to get it down to temperature. I imagine 5 gallons of boiling liquid can take a while to get down!

Comment: Yes, I use a homemade immersion chiller.  I also use a March 809 pump to do recirculated chilling.

Comment: Cool thanks, i'm lucky to have a great specialist beer shop in town so i'll see what he has. Failing that there's always eBay to pick up a few bits and pieces!